# Select menu not changing when model changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a select menu as follows:

```
<select ng-model="selected_event_type.event_type"
        ng-options="event_type.name for event_type in events.event_type_views">
    <option value="">Event type</option>
</select>
```

I also have the following separate select menu:

```
<select ng-model="current_event"
        ng-options="event.event_id for event in current_level.events.event"
        ng-change="currentEventChanged()">
</select>
```

The first select menu works as expected. In the currentEventChanged() method for the second select menu, I change the value of selected_event_type.event_type, but the first select menu doesn't update to reflect this, and I can't figure out why.

Below is the relevant code from my controller:

```
$scope.selected_event_type = {
    event_type: null
};

$scope.events = {
    event_type_views: [
        {name: 'Collision', partial: 'views/events/collision.html'},
        {name: 'Boundary', partial: 'views/events/boundary.html'},
        {name: 'Timer', partial: 'views/events/timer.html'},
        {name: 'Input', partial: 'views/events/input.html'}
    ]
}

$scope.currentEventChanged = function () {
    var current_event_type;
    var current_event_partial;

    for (var key in $scope.current_event.event_type) {
        current_event_type = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
    }

    current_event_partial = 'views/events/' + current_event_type + '.html';

    $scope.selected_event_type = {
        event_type: {
            name: current_event_type,
            partial: current_event_partial
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: not cleaed from plunker code

Comment: @ThomasPons Please don't do that. Questions are meant to be self-contained. If you keep asking people to take their questions and turn them into "plonkrs", you're defeating the purpose of this site, and dragging down the quality of our Q&A.

Comment: @meagar sorry but these problems are technical you prefer a plunkr and two answers and happy guy with a good solution or a thread with 50 answers and a guy disappointed ... I don't care about stackoverflow i care about people which have difficulties

Comment: @ThomasPons Then this is not the right site for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know the problem. You are binding your first list to list `events.event_type_views`.  And the model to `selected_event_type.event_type`. When a elment is selected model get update to selected object(such as `{name: 'Collision', partial: 'views/events/collision.html'}`).

`currentEventChanged` method cannot create a new object and set value as the comparison is done based on reference to what has been selected in dropdown. The logic in the method should not create a new object, instead should select the object from the existing list like

```
$scope.selected_event_type.event_type= $scope.events.event_type_views[0]; //Logic to search the array events.event_type_views and find an element and assign
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! I figured if I set selected_event_type.event_type as an object which has the same properties and values as the corresponding one from events.event_type_views, the select would 'match' them and update itself. You're right though, it's actually compared by reference, not by properties/values.